# iphone - get assigning to incompatible type error when using tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios

I am an ios development newbie. I get an error when I try to do

```
tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

The error is "Assigning to 'id UITabBarControllerDelegate ' from incompatible type "MyAppDelegate *""

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I call this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of my app delegate if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your `MyAppDelegate` implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol.

In the interface for `MyAppDelegate` mark it with `@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>`

The `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>` shows that you implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol which is what is expected for the `tabBarController.delegate`

Comment: UIApplicationDelegate is a protocol as well, not a class. The correct declaration would be `@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>`

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thats what I get for coding into SO